# Resolving Sample Bias in Text Classification - Python - ADASYN

Tags: python, sampling, text-classification

I am currently working on a project where I have scraped reviews relating to a retailer from a review website. The aim is to use a Random Forest classifier to classify each review in the dataset by subject; 'Delivery' or 'Customer Service'.

After looking at the dataset, over 90% of the reviews (both training and test data) relate to 'Delivery'. I have been advised by my lecturer that we need to account for sample bias. I've researched this and tried to implement some correction in Python below using ADASYN (near the bottom of the code below):

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 10
TextFileReader = pd.read_csv('TestToSentimentAnalyse.csv', chunksize=chunksize, header=None)
dataset = pd.concat(TextFileReader, ignore_index=False)
dataset.columns = ['Reviews', 'Delivery', 'Customer_Service', 'Purchase_Date', 'Likelihood_to_Recommend',
                   'Overall_Satisfaction', 'Location', 'Date_Published', 'Sentiment']
dataset = dataset.iloc[1:]

# Cleaning the texts
import re

corpus = []
for i in range(1, 29779):
    corpus.append(review)

# Creating the Bag of Words model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

# Set up dependant variable - delivery is 0, customer service is 1
y = []
for i in range(1, 29779):
    if dataset['Delivery'][i] == '2':
        y.append(1)
    elif dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == '2':
        y.append(0)
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == '0' and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == '0':
        y.append(0.5)  ## flaw in this as we had to choose one
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == '1' and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == '1':
        y.append(0.5)  ## flaw in this as we had to choose one
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == '0' and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == '1':
        y.append(0)
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == '1' and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == '0':
        y.append(1)
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == 2:
        y.append(1)
    elif dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == 2:
        y.append(0)
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == 0 and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == 0:
        y.append(0.5)  ## flaw in this as we had to choose one
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == 1 and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == 1:
        y.append(0.5)  ## flaw in this as we had to choose one
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == 0 and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == 1:
        y.append(0)
    elif dataset['Delivery'][i] == 1 and dataset['Customer_Service'][i] == 0:
        y.append(1)
    else:
        y.append('Needs Review')

get_indexes = lambda y, xs: [i for (j, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if y == j]
del_idx = get_indexes('Needs Review', y)
del_idx.sort(reverse=True)

import numpy as np

for item in del_idx:
    y = np.delete(y, (item), axis=0)
    X = np.delete(X, (item), axis=0)

from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN

ada = ADASYN(random_state=42)
X_ada, y_ada = ada.fit_sample(X, y)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_ada, y_ada, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

classifier_10E = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, criterion='entropy', random_state=0)
classifier_10E.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_10E = classifier_10E.predict(X_test)
```

I ran the code overnight (it works quickly without the ADASYN function) and it didn't finish. I am processing roughly 32,000 reviews. The aim of running this is to create dummy entries for the underrepresented class in my sample ('Customer Service'), so the Random Forest classifier is better trained. At the moment, I could blindly predict 'Delivery' for all reviews in my test data and be correct 90%+ of the time.

I would be grateful if someone could point out if I am doing something wrong or if there is a better option available in Python.

Thanks